# Raphael JS: Moving an image along path after delay

Tags: javascript, raphael

I currently have an animation so that slides across the background image:

```
var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 800, 600);
var anim = Raphael.animation({path: "M2 2L100 2"}, 1500);
var frontLayer = paper.image("raphael-img/front-image.png",0,0,1700,600);
c.animate({transform: ['t',-900,0]}, 14000, function(){})
```

This produces the result of:

[Beginning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eqUq.png)

[Process of sliding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0eNm.png)

Is there a way to immediately change the background / the sliding effect after 4 seconds. Without it having to scroll across.

Comment: End image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7w9BA.png ( Not enough reputation points  to add the image in my question )

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found out how to do it.

Simply, call the **effect** you wish to use a delay by doing:

var anim = Raphael.animation(**{transform: ['t', -900, 0]},0**);

Then get your image variable name you assigned and use the following function.

**frontLayer**.animate(anim.delay(2000));